# How do I load test/resources instead of main/resources?

Tags: java, testing, properties, intellij-idea

[ I asked this question on 29JUL2014, but on 31JUL2014 everything just started working again, and I didn't make any changes. ]

In a Java project (in IntelliJ), I have marked:

- `src/main/java` as Sources Root
- `src/test/java` as Test Sources Root
- `src/main/resources` as Resources Root
- `src/test/resources` as Test Resources Root

I have a file:  `test/java/Test1.java`

in which I try to load a `config.properties` file that's in `src/test/resources`, but what gets loaded is the `config.properties` that's in `src/main/resources`.  I've had other projects where my test resources file loaded correctly.  I'm not sure why in this project I'm not making that happen.  I do have elsewhere in the project a `PropertiesUtil.loadProperties` static method that does this:

```
String filename = "config.properties";
input = PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

Is that why I'm not getting the correct `config.properties` file?  How do I load the test `config.properties`?

Comment: can you try just with getResource(filename);

Comment: I would suggest renaming of the test config.properties, and choose the right file in the runtime.

Comment: No, this should work as is. Test resources are placed first on the classpath by default, so they should be referenced instead of the main resources. You have a different problem that is screwing up the natural order of things. Can you post your pom?

Comment: There's no pom for this project, I decided to try gradle, so I don't have a pom.  I agree, I thought this should have worked as is.

Comment: Well today everything working fine, and I didn't change anything.